# Buscar valores de una lista dentro de una lista de listas

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de encontrar los elementos de str2 en str1. 
Basicamente, si b y c se encuentra en el item[1] de str1 pero lo que estoy obteniendo es:

```
>>> nueva
[['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']]
```

cuando deberia obtener:

```
>>> nueva
[['a1', 'b1', 'c1']]

str1 = [['a1','b1','c1']]
str2 = ['b','c']

nueva = []

for itema in str2:
    for item in str1:
        itema.find(item[1])
        nueva.append(item)
```

Comment: `itema.find(item[1])` no hace nada, te falta un condicional aquí que compruebe si la letra se encuentra o no en cada palabra. Por cierto no debería ser `[['b1', 'c1']]` para el ejemplo que das? ¿Solo quieres comprobar la primera letra de la cadena o en toda la cadena?

Comment: Solo quiero que todos los items que haya en str2 los busque en b1 de str1 @FJSevilla

Comment: if itema in item[1]: con esto lo solucione!